# ValueError when fitting OLS model using statsmodels

Tags: python

```
# adding constant to the train data
x_train1 = sm.add_constant(x_train) # adding constant to the test data
x_test1 = sm.add_constant(x_test) # Complete the code to add constant to the test data

olsmodel1 = sm.OLS(x_train, y_train).fit()
olsmodel1
# checking for missing values
df.isnull().sum()
## Complete the code to check missing values in all the columns
​
brand_name            0
os                    0
screen_size           0
4g                    0
5g                    0
main_camera_mp      179
selfie_camera_mp      2
int_memory            4
ram                   4
battery               6
weight                7
release_year          0
days_used             0
new_price             0
used_price            0
used_price_log        0
new_price_log         0
device_category       0
dtype: int64
print(olsmodel1.summary())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6j/zjjqp3y160ddq0qjnph_7r0w0000gp/T/ipykernel_29575/2464932037.py in <module>
----> 1 print(olsmodel1.summary())

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in summary(self, yname, xname, title, alpha)
   2638         rsquared_type = '' if self.k_constant else ' (uncentered)'
   2639         top_right = [('R-squared' + rsquared_type + ':',
-> 2640                       ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared]),
   2641                      ('Adj. R-squared' + rsquared_type + ':',
   2642                       ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared_adj]),

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in rsquared(self)
   1715             return 1 - self.ssr/self.centered_tss
   1716         else:
-> 1717             return 1 - self.ssr/self.uncentered_tss
   1718 
   1719     @cache_readonly

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in ssr(self)
   1654         """Sum of squared (whitened) residuals."""
   1655         wresid = self.wresid
-> 1656         return np.dot(wresid, wresid)
   1657 
   1658     @cache_readonly

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (2417,47) and (2417,47) not aligned: 47 (dim 1) != 2417 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OLS` model from `statsmodels` uses arguments for the data in a different order than is used for `scikit-learn`, meaning that the exogenous variables come second after the endogenous variable (see also [the statsmodels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html).

```
olsmodel1 = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train).fit()
```